# How to write SQL Query for this condition?

Tags: sql

I have following table in my database

```
---------------------
|ID    |Date     
---------------------
|15    |2015-07-01
|15    |2015-07-02
|15    |2015-07-03
|18    |2015-07-04
|18    |2015-07-05
|22    |2015-07-06
|22    |2015-07-07
|22    |2015-07-08
```

I am writing this query

```
select * from table where date = "2015-07-04";
```

by this code i can get current id but how can i select next id to my current id.

I know only date and want to retrieve data.
like i have date=2015-07-03 and on that date id=15
so i want result containing all rows related to id=15 and also id next to id=15 that is id=18;

Comment: With this code you don't get current id, you get all rows for the provided date.

Comment: What do you mean by "*by this code i can get current id*"? According to your input data, this query should return first 4rows of data. What is *current* id in this case and what is *next to curernt*?

Comment: what you mean with 'next id'? next id same date? next id randomly chosen among the ids of the next day? what if next day there is no entry?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is your `current ID`? And what is the result you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure.. But, seems like you are looking for this

```
select max(id)+1 from yourTable;
```

If you are using `Oracle`, then create [SEQUENCE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm) and use `NEXTVAL` to get next sequence value. If you are using `SQL Server`, then you can select `AUTO INCREMENT` option.